# Solidity. Check if key has value in mapping. Operator != not compatible with types struct

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I am new to solidity. I have a Person struct and mapping:

```
 struct Person{
        uint age;
        string gender;
    }

 Person[] players; // holds the 24 players

 mapping (string => Person) selectedPair;
```

I have to chose a boy and a girl.

```
function choosePair() public {
        // save the chosen person in selectedPair if its the correct gender
        for (uint i=0; i<players.length; i++) {
            Person storage chosenOne = players[pseudoRandom(0,23)]; 
            if(selectedPair[chosenOne.gender] != 0){ //error!
                // I want to know if there is a "girl" already in the selectedPair mapping. 
            }
        }
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Operator != not compatible with types struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedPair` is a `mapping` of **string**s to `Person` **struct**s.

That is to say, `selectedPair[A_STRING_HERE]` will always return a `Person` **struct**, regardless of the value of `A_STRING_HERE` (which has to be a **string**).

You have defined the `Person` struct as having one **uint** property called `age`, and one **string** property called `gender`.

So to get the `gender` property of the above, you would need to call it like this

```
selectedPair[A_STRING_HERE].gender
```

But note, we can't directly compare strings. So if you want to compare the `gender` value against something else, you will need to hash both values and compare their hashes.

```
if( 
   keccak256(abi.encodePacked(selectedPair[A_STRING_HERE].gender)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(SOME_OTHER_STRING))
)
```

This will resolve the error reported in the question.

Comment: But the keys in the mapping are not Persons, they are strings like: `{"girl"=Person, "boy"=0}. That would be a selected pair that is missing the boy. I wouild like to know if there is already a "boy", for example. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: A mapping of **string** to `Person` will never have 0 as a value. If its unassigned, it will be mapped to a Person that has empty values. That is, `age=0` and `gender=""`